# Running View Controllers in background

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, background, nstimer

In the main View Controller I have two buttons for Board1 and Board2 . When I press Board 1 I need to navigate to a new View controller and start a timer and I should be able to return back to the main page and press Board 2 and start a new timer for board 2 in a new View controller. THe problem occurs such that if I start the timer and return back to the Main page and then return back to the view controller for board 1 the timer has stopped already though I have not pressed the Stop button. What kind of segue do I need to provide between the main view controller and the new view controller. Also in the new View controller I have a field called 
"Name" . This also gets deleted on returning back.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a singleton class that has the NSTimer entities you need (in your case firstTimer and secondTimer), you would access them from the corresponding view controller and start them when the button is pressed, they would still run in the background.

Comment: HI Sheisd, thanks for the reply. But am not sure if I understand it clearly . Could you please elaborate ? Should I create a Single ton class for each board ?

Comment: @SadhanaManiarasu I edited the answer so it is more explicit.